Embedded Derby crashing on shutting down the parent process with interrupted exception and deleting files
We are using Derby derby-10.14.2.0 along with openjdk 1.8.0_402.
When we shutdown the parent process sometimes derby DB gives interrupted exceptions and deletes its "DO NO TOUCH" files and property files and it does not come back up again and we have to manually delete the db and start afresh. This is leading to loss of data that was stored in db.
Below is the snippet of log

ERROR 08000: Connection closed by unknown interrupt.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.util.InterruptStatus.setInterrupted(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.util.InterruptStatus.throwIf(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BasicNoPutResultSetImpl.checkCancellationFlag(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BulkTableScanResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ProjectRestrictResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ScalarAggregateResultSet.getRowFromResultSet(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ScalarAggregateResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ProjectRestrictResultSet.getNextRowCore(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.BasicNoPutResultSetImpl.getNextRow(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.movePosition(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.next(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:659)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:635)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1165)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)

snippet 2

Fri May 24 15:01:23 IST 2024: Shutting down Derby engine
Fri May 24 15:01:23 IST 2024 Thread[,5,main]
ERROR XJ001: Java exception: ': org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.ShutdownException'.
java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: ': org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.ShutdownException'.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.commit(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.commit(PoolingDataSource.java:211)

Derby should preserve data in case of shutdown.

Are you absolutely sure that it's Derby that's deleting those files? How can you tell? Perhaps something else is deleting the Derby files.

You need to shutdown Derby before main process terminates, see here:

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");

This will shutdown all databases and the Derby engine!
Also:

A clean shutdown always throws SQL exception XJ015, which can be ignored.

